# fancybox and playlist work locally but not online

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jplayer

I'm developing a website where users will upload media in various formats to create a story.  My "story view" page has four draggable divs with four types of media: photos, audio clips, scanned documents and videos.  The audio player is jquery's jplayer, adapted to use a dynamic playlist from a mysql database.  When the user clicks on a photo, document or video, a lightbox should load via fancybox.  This works locally (with some minor bugs), but not online.  The photos load, but not the audio playlist (I don't have the videos loaded online), and when you click on a photo you get this error in the web console: $.fancybox is not a function.

I looked at related posts and tried to use another path (the online path) but it didn't seem to have an effect.

You can see the development website here:
http://cdonahue.web44.net/LifeStorIntegration22AugOnline/lifestor2.html

if you login with username "2" and password "password" you'll get to a story page.  Choose the first one ("Inch Beach") to see the story view.  To see the code for any of the scripts called, go back to the LifeStorIntegration22AugOnline directory.

Please let me know if you need additional info -- thanks for any help.

Comment: it seems like the fancybox js file is not in the place you say it is, this link return a 404 http://cdonahue.web44.net/LifeStorIntegration22AugOnline/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js

Answer (score 2):

My English seems not good. But this will help you..

Just Delete all the comment lines in the jquery.fancybox.js

All of the browsers got confused with the comment line and the next line.